# how to implement dropbox in android application with REST API

Tags: android

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs is the best place, But I cannot get the proper answer, I want to implement dropbox in my android application with REST api, I don't want User Log in screen, want to put username and password dynamically.

Any idea or code snippet for this Question?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some stage, you have to enter the UN/PW - you then get a token (as described here:

Passwords And Tokens

You only need to ask for your user's login information once for authentication. Upon successful authentication, you'll received a consumer key and secret pair you can sign for a token for all further calls. This is all done using the /token API method.

YOu can store the token and reuse that for authentication

Comment: Here is a link to the sample code on the dropbox website - you can use this as a "startup" to your app......   https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-0.1.tar.gz